# pynput.keyboard is not working on chromebook

Tags: python, pynput

I am using pynput.keyboard for a tutorial I am following. I am using the debian distribution of linux, and used this way to download pycharm: https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2020/11/how-to-install-pycharm-on-chromebook.html

this is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(5)

for char in 'insert text here':
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

if i run it while my main window is pycharm, it types the text entered in `for char in 'insert text here':`
but if i run it in any other window, it does not type. can anyone help

Comment: what `"other window"`? Some programs may get keys in differen way, or not get any key.